# Boundaries for background

Tags: actionscript-3, bounding-box, bounds

I am using as3 and try to drag the background within the screen. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
Here is my code:

```
bg.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(-bg.width + stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, bg.width - stage.stageWidth, bg.height - stage.stageHeight));
```

Comment: The boundaries seems to be pretty much correct in sense of geometry. So, define **wrong**.

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ I could not test your code so please **describe the problem**. What seems "wrong" to your eyes?? Also in your `mouse_move` function did you check positions / boundaries there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it didn’t work properly when the background was with a transparent background like this. That is, the flash had green rectangles without a common rectangular background.
[image]